# ControlTemplate.Trigger not working on CellValuePresenter (TargetType)

Tags: wpf, triggers, infragistics, controltemplate, xamdatagrid

I 'm using Infragistics 2014.2. I have a XamDataGrid which display the data with dynamic columns, the grid is formatted by its default style and in addition, some of the columns having alignment set to Right (decimal type columns) with some value masking on it and the rest are set alignment to Left.

I want to remove the default CellValuePresenter style of XamDataGrid and write a new style with only TextBlock/ContentPresenter on it instead of CellValuePresenter for each cell and after applying new style, the alignment and masking of the cells should remain same. The reason behind applying this new style is i want the copy of the same grid to display it on another window with no data manipulation in it.

Can you please look at the following code that i have tried to achieve the same(even with many of the changes in it), but it doesn't seems to work anyhow.

```
    <Style x:Key="PreviewCellValuePresenterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate x:Name="CellValuePresenterControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentValuePresenter"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                     ContentSource="Value"
                                     Margin="4,3,4,4"/>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right">
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentValuePresenter" Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right">
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentValuePresenter" Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Right now, i'm only setting the alignment property for testing. In the above code, have tried TextBlock in place of ContentPresenter but the trigger never gets invoked. I don't where i'm doing wrong.

Can you anyone help me to get out of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
If your intention of using text block is only for alignment/appearance, then you can just use setters to set these values. 

            <Style x:Key="PreviewCellValuePresenterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}" >
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
             </Style>

But, If you need some other implementations like value masking, or need text block to be there, 


 <Style x:Key="PreviewCellValuePresenterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
                                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
                                                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource TextStyle}">
                                                                </TextBlock>
                                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                </Style>


    <Style x:Key="TextStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">

            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>

            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      </Style>
```